# How to turn off ffmpeg hardware acceleration

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, libav

I have a video player. Written in C++ with Visual Studio, using the ffmpeg 3.2.2 libav libraries. I need to be able to programmatically turn off hardware acceleration of video decompression. I'm not finding much discussion on turning off hardware acceleration; the only info I found is here on StackOverflow: [How to turn off Video Acceleration programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913052/how-to-turn-off-video-acceleration-programatically) But that solution looks global to the system, not just my application.
Are there any ffmpeg flags or APIs that enable turning off hardware acceleration? VLC, which uses ffmpeg's libav libs, has an option to turn hardware acceleration off, so there much be some local-to-the-application method...

Comment: VLC is open source software. If it implements a feature you need, have a look at it's [source code](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html).

Comment: I am. It is large... there is an option to modify hw accel of demux'ing, which is what I want, but the docs say it is off by default. I'm trying to locate in the code where that happens, but the code is large...

Comment: I guess hardware acceleration isn't enabled by default in ffmpeg. If you want to use it, you have to enable the specific hw acceleration you need while building ffmpeg and use the special codec that uses this acceleration eg: h264_qsv for Intel's QSV